# How to write the sql in SQLite with this?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, common-table-expression

```
    WITH cteCountDownlines AS
( --=== Count each occurrence of EmployeeID in the sort path
 SELECT EmployeeID = CAST(SUBSTRING(h.SortPath,t.N,4) AS INT), 
        NodeCount  = COUNT(*) --Includes current node
   FROM dbo.Hierarchy h, 
        dbo.HTally t
  WHERE t.N BETWEEN 1 AND DATALENGTH(SortPath)
  GROUP BY SUBSTRING(h.SortPath,t.N,4)
) --=== Update the NodeCount and calculate the RightBower
 UPDATE h
    SET h.NodeCount  = downline.NodeCount,
        h.RightBower = (downline.NodeCount - 1) * 2 + LeftBower + 1
   FROM dbo.Hierarchy h
   JOIN cteCountDownlines downline
     ON h.EmployeeID = downline.EmployeeID
;
```

that is from https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hierarchies-on-steroids-1-convert-an-adjacency-list-to-nested-sets.
I have tried many ways but not work.
The separated cteCountDownlines and join works just fine, but don't knwo how to conbine them

Comment: What is your version of SQLite?

Comment: How exactly is this not working -- looks fine.

Comment: @forpas I tried to use join in SQLite and none of them work..And I go well with a version without JOIN at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQLite 3.33.0+ you can use the [`UPDATE...FROM`](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) syntax:

```
WITH cteCountDownlines AS (
 SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(h.SortPath,t.N,4) AS INT) EmployeeID, 
        COUNT(*) NodeCount
  FROM Hierarchy h INNER JOIN HTally t
  ON t.N BETWEEN 1 AND LENGTH(h.SortPath)
  GROUP BY SUBSTR(h.SortPath,t.N,4)
)
UPDATE Hierarchy AS h
SET NodeCount  = downline.NodeCount,
    RightBower = (downline.NodeCount - 1) * 2 + h.LeftBower + 1
FROM cteCountDownlines downline
WHERE h.EmployeeID = downline.EmployeeID;
```

For SQLite 3.15.0+ you can use this syntax:

```
WITH cteCountDownlines AS (
 SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(h.SortPath,t.N,4) AS INT) EmployeeID, 
        COUNT(*) NodeCount
  FROM Hierarchy h INNER JOIN HTally t
  ON t.N BETWEEN 1 AND LENGTH(h.SortPath)
  GROUP BY SUBSTR(h.SortPath,t.N,4)
)
UPDATE Hierarchy AS h
SET (NodeCount, RightBower) = (
  SELECT downline.NodeCount,
         (downline.NodeCount - 1) * 2 + h.LeftBower + 1
  FROM cteCountDownlines downline
  WHERE h.EmployeeID = downline.EmployeeID
);
```

Note that there is no equivalent to SQL Server's [`DATALENGTH()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function.
The function [`LENGTH()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#length) I used returns the number of chars in a string.

Comment: Thank you so much! Meanwhile, I tried to finished my version, which seem works and exacly like yours...http://codepad.org/OXTMDKg7 (my table name is different) and I am confused why his version used JOIN? There seems no join operation at all.

Comment: @T.Worm The page of the link in your question uses SQL Server syntax, which is not supported by SQLite. SQLite's UPDATE FROM syntax is Postgres-like.

Comment: Sorry, this may be out of the topic. I used this  http://codepad.org/P5E6jLcT instead of something like  CAST(anchor.EmployeeID AS BINARY(4)) . I am wondering if this will cause performance or not?

Comment: There is no BINARY data type in SQLite. Read this: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html As for the rest of the code the only thing I can say by a first glance is that a recursive query (depending on the depth of the recursion) may be bad for performance.